# Bluetooth started cancelling my internet connection!

Tags: bluetooth, internet

The PC is quite old but works fine, my first time with linux. Installed 22.10. I have been trying to link my bluetooth earphones today, today if I activate my bluetooth in settings or on the top right and I leave the system for about 2 or 3 minutes, the internet connection stops working. Despite this I can see the internet link is absolutely fine, I can swich it on, swich it off, it finds the link, but if I want to go to a page... it just waits and waits. It never says no internet is available. But when I swich the bluetooth off again and wait for 2 or 3 minutes... the internet works 100%.
So it is quite difficult and useless to find a answer because even if they worked, I would not be able to use them for anything because I cannot get online.

If this will make any difference, if I go to the settings page, and swhich bluetooth on (there it does the same), but it just keeps on searching for devices and never finds these even though they are switched on. To see if the earphones worked I tried them on my phone and they are 100% and they always worked on Windows. But the problem is obviously the fact that my online link stops.
Also, I have a SAMSUNG phone linked to bluetooth, which is not connected on settings (that I eventually got linked the other day... but still not the headphones that I am trying today). ? Something to do with the fact that the SAMSUNG is linked (but switched off) AND I did not have this problem while I was trying to link the phone??

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks
Johan

lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)

```
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express
```

Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0880]

```
Kernel driver in use: r8169

Kernel modules: r8169
```

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565

Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)

```
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless
```

Network Adapter [105b:e07f]

```
Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c6e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.

Laptop Integrated WebCam HD

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

[sudo] password for johan:

[    0.131064] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls

[    0.177561] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

[   33.637155] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22

[   33.637201] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family

[   33.637203] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized

[   33.637364] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized

[   33.637368] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized

[   33.637375] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

[   46.474736] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3

[   46.474747] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast

[   46.474756] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

[   77.779773] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized

[   77.779785] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized

[   77.779797] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: you could try `sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1` and see if it improves

Comment: Hi... Thank you very much for the help, this is amazing now that they work. Enjoy your day, Johan

Comment: If you don't want to have to run that after every reboot do `echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`