# Wifi Adapter QCA9565 Keep Disappearing, Is Uninstalling Windows a Solution?

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 with Windows 8.1 and my Wifi adapter keeps disappearing(Wifi adapter not found) after a few minutes or hours, I looked up here to find people with similar problem and already tried some of the solutions. It worked for a few days until my Wifi adapter started disappearing again.
So far I have tried:

- Turning off fast startup on Windows
- Making sure I used full shutdown after using Windows
- Using High Performance power setting on Windows
- Unchecked "Allow Windows to turn off this device to save power"
  option on my Wifi adapter in device manager
- Turning off Wifi power management in Ubuntu by using `sudo sed -i"s/wifi.powersave= 3/wifi.powersave= 2/g" /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

As you can see, my problems often come from my Windows. At first I thought it was because I don't have the wifi adapter driver installed on Windows (before it was simply "Network Controller" under Other Devices in Device Manager with no driver installed), so I installed a driver based on the information I get from `sudo lshw -C network`. It works until it doesn't, and the Device Manager keep saying that the Wifi Adapter is not connected to my laptop every time the problem occurs, sometimes it says it does not have enough free resource to be able to work, so I have to uninstall and reinstall the driver on Windows to make it work on my Ubuntu.

Right now, I disabled the Wifi Adapter on my Windows and so far it works, but I want to anticipate if the problem resurfaces again.

I'm wondering if Windows is the root of my problem. This is my first time using Ubuntu and I already liking it better than using Windows. Will uninstalling Windows solve my problem? Or will it causes more problem for my Ubuntu experience in general? Is there any solutions I haven't tried or possible causes of my problem I haven't realized?

I am still not very familiar with Ubuntu or code in general, so if there is a command that I should put on the terminal to provide more info, please do tell me.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461892/bluetooth-started-cancelling-my-internet-connection ? It doesn't officially have an answer, but there is a `modprobe` command (hidden in the comments) that appears to have helped. Worth a try.

Comment: It does feel somewhat familiar, although I don't have any device connected via bluetooth. When the Wifi Adapter disconnects from the PC and cannot find enough resource, I do try to disable/re-enable the bluetooth from the device manager to make space. I'll try that thread when the problem comes back again, thank you!

Comment: Is this a dual boot, or are you using WSL? Please update your question with this information?

Comment: @mpboden I think it's dual boot, it's the first time I've heard of WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple things you might try.
Make sure you applied all Ubuntu updates. There was an update just prior to June 30 that (so far) cured my wifi problems.
I also found this command on Launchpad.net.

echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwififix.conf > /dev/null

It creates the file iwlwififix.conf in /etc/modprobe.d with the contents of the echo command. Supposedly it transfers decription from the wifi driver to the CPU.

I applied both update and this command at the same time, but verifying found out that wifi stays put with just the updates.